# customise endpoint urls in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoints

I'm trying to create a tabbed version of "My Account" in woocommerce.
I have built my pages in php using bootstrap css and included the wordpress header and footer so the page loads correctly.
The tabs display as expected by I am having an issue with the endpoint urls in woocommerce:

```
- 'edit-address'

- 'view-order'
```

These endpoints are generated dynamically and appended to the url: www.site-name.com/my-account/edit-address
Here's the function call (in file .plugins/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-address.php):

```
<a href="<?php echo wc_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-address', $name  ); ?>
```

I've included 'my-addresses' in my tabbed page which dispays ok. However, the link to edit the shipping and billing addresses is generated by the above call to the endpoints. When the link is clicked the page fails to load and returns a 404 error.

My custom php page is basically www.site-name.com/account/edit-address

The problem is:

- The 'edit-address' page content is not loading and I get a 404 error

I'm guessing the issue is caused because my pages are external php pages and not stored with wp database?

Is there a way I can customise the endpoint url so it appends correctly and loads the page?

Link to the page on my site: `www.thecookerytutor dot co dot uk/account`

Origional woocommerce my-account page: `www.thecookerytutor dot co dot uk/my-account`
(You will need to create a login to view both pages)

It's had me stumped for days!
Thanks in advance.

Code for my addresses tab on my custom php page as promised...

```
echo "<div id = 'edit-addresses' class='tab-pane fade'>";
                echo "<div id = 'content' class = 'page col-full'>";
                echo "<section id = 'main' class = 'col-left'>";
                echo "<BR>";
                        include "my-address.php";
                echo "</section>";
            echo "</div>";
     echo "</div>";`
```

As you can see I'm including the wc page that loads the addresses (I've copied to the local folder)
Here's the content of edit-address.php (I've copied to my local folder and added wp header). The page loads the header but the get address function fails at line 50.

```
<?php 

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); 

require('../wp-blog-header.php');

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wp_title_so_18381106', 10, 3 );
function wp_title_so_18381106( $title, $sep, $seplocation ) 
{
  return 'Your Account | ';
}

get_header();
?>
<?php
/**
 * Edit address form
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $current_user;

$page_title = ( $load_address === 'billing' ) ? __( 'Billing Address', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Shipping Address', 'woocommerce' );

get_currentuserinfo();

?>

<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

<?php //if ( ! $load_address ) : ?>

    <?php //wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-address.php' ); ?>

<?php //else : ?>
    <form method="post">

        <h3><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_edit_address_title', $page_title ); ?></h3>

        <?php do_action( "woocommerce_before_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>
```

/*fails to load here*/

```
<?php foreach ( $address as $key => $field ) : ?>

                <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, ! empty( $_POST[ $key ] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST[ $key ] ) : $field['value'] ); ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php do_action( "woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="save_address" value="<?php _e( 'Save Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-edit_address' ); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_address" />
            </p>

        </form>

    <?php //endif; ?>
```

Comment: what url are you getting? and what should have been the correct url?

Comment: The url is now appending correctly: www.site-name.com/account/edit-address/billing but I still get a 404 error.

Comment: so there's no problem now?

Comment: not loading content for 'edit-address'...404 error i've amended my question

Comment: try visiting your permalink settings page.. in the admin dashboard, visit Settings > Permalinks. Just view it, then check if you still get 404 on your edit-address

Comment: sorry don't see how this will help?

Comment: I can't explain it here on comment section.. it's too long.. just try it.

Comment: ok, view permalinks page, then refreshed page...still get 404

Comment: I've tried: `woocommerce_get_page_id( 'edit_address' );` but think this is depectiated now?

Comment: There's a function here that seems helpful: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_page_id.html#40-62 `function wc_edit_address_i18n( $id, $flip = false ) {
    $slugs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_edit_address_slugs', array(
        'billing'  => sanitize_title( _x( 'billing', 'edit-address-slug', 'woocommerce' ) ),
        'shipping' => sanitize_title( _x( 'shipping', 'edit-address-slug', 'woocommerce' ) )
    ) );`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `wc_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' )` produces `http://example.com/my-account/edit-address` which links to the appropriate section.  I would advise trying to isolate the issue by switching to a default theme and disabling other plugins.

Comment: Hi, that will work...my url points to an external php page: /account/edit-address/ not /my-account/edit-address/

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce is a plugin for WordPress, you can't use it without WordPress... for example `/my-account/edit-address/`, that `my-account` is actually the page you are rendering and `edit-address` is just a variable. `edit-address` was added as an endpoint to `my-account`. you need to do the same for your `account`.

You should get an idea of [what endpoints are](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/).

Other thoughts about this. If you really want to use `account` and not `my-account`, look into your pages for "My Account" and change it's permalink. You can also create another page that can use `account` in it's permalink. Then use that page in your WooCommerce > Settings > Account tab > My Account Page.

If you have some custom php codes, you can just copy the template from your woocommerce plugin to your theme folder and edit the file you need. Read [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

And if I have not addressed your problem, comment down below.

Comment: Thanks. As I said in my original question I included Wordpress's template header and footer so the custom php pages load as expected. Everything is fine apart from the end points, which as you say are a variable and do not point to any page as such. What I need is to get the content from edit-address to load on address rather than the default my address. At the moment it is giving a 404 page not found error.

Comment: I do not know how you are doing it. I can't suggest more.

Comment: I've updated my question for clarification and provided a link to my site. If you create an account I can show you the page behaviour. Thanks for your help @Reigel.

Comment: it would be great if you could provide some codes.. or something so that anyone would know how or why you are doing it. My mind is puzzled as to why you need to have some external php pages and I'm not sure what you mean about "not stored with wp database". There are so many questions in my mind. Like, is some-file.php in the theme? or what. I get your question, but I don't get why you have that question. So it's hard to answer.

Comment: Several reasons...but for this page I wanted to create a tabbed version of my account dashboard. I used bootstrap to build the nav-tabs and included the wp header and footer. I'll post some code but I don't think it will help as the issue is to do with the url and endpoint not fetching the page and loading the content. Not stored in wp database means, since i have built my php outside of wp the end points would lookup the page id from the db and load the content?

Comment: I may have found a solutions at this post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67732/setting-a-custom-sub-path-for-blog-without-using-pages

Comment: I'll need to test it and report back. Just trying to get my head around the code in that post...but it looks like it might do what I need.

Comment: Don't think `add_rewrite_rule` will work as this redirects a url to a page. I don't have a page to redirect to - I need to load the wc edit address content on my php page.

Comment: I have managed to link to the adit-address page and got part of it to load, but the form to edit the address fails. See above code. @helgatheviking

Comment: I'm know thinking RewriteRule may work? But not sure how to implement? I need to change my url from /my-account/edit-address/billing to /account/edit-address/billing and load the endpoint page content for billing address